# Why doesn't my logger output from non-main modules?

Tags: python, logging

I have the following file structure:

```
config.yaml
main.py
tools/
 misc_utils.py
 extractor.py
```

`misc_utils.py` contains the following function to retrieve my logger:

```
import logging
import logging.config

def get_logger(module_name, config=None):
    if config is not None:
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    return logging.getLogger(module_name)
```

In `main.py`, I call that function:

```
from tools.misc_utils import get_logger
import tools.extractor
with open('config.yaml') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f)
logger = get_logger(__name__, config=config)
logger.info("this outputs ok")
```

If I call `extractor.py` from `main.py`, as the import line in `main.py` does, it doesn't output anything for some reason:

```
from .misc_utils import get_logger

logger = get_logger(__name__, 'config.yaml')
logger.info("this doesn't appear in the log")
```

And finally here is `config.yaml`:

```
# Logging
version: 1
formatters:
    default:
        format: '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        stream: ext://sys.stdout
        formatter: default
        level: DEBUG
    file:
        class: logging.FileHandler
        filename: main.log
        formatter: default
        level: DEBUG
root:
    handlers: [console, file]
    level: DEBUG
```

My question is, why is nothing outputted in extractor.py?

Answer (score 0):

With extractor.py containing this code:

```
import yaml
from .misc_utils import get_logger

with open('config.yaml') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f)

logger = get_logger(__name__, config=config)
logger.info("this doesn't appear in the log")
logger.info("this doesn't appear in the log")
```

and main.py looking like this:

```
import yaml
from tools.misc_utils import get_logger

from tools import extractor

with open('config.yaml') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f)
logger = get_logger(__name__, config=config)
logger.info("this outputs ok")
```

it works for me. Here's the output:

```
$ python3 main.py
2016-02-24 23:10:51,314 tools.extractor INFO     this doesn't appear in the log
2016-02-24 23:10:51,320 __main__     INFO     this outputs ok
```

**Alternatively**, if you just want to use an existing logger in
extractor.py, i.e:

```
from .misc_utils import get_logger

logger = get_logger(__name__)
logger.info("this doesn't appear in the log")
```

Then it is important that the logger was initialized before the
import. With this in main.py:

```
import yaml
from tools.misc_utils import get_logger

with open('config.yaml') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f)
logger = get_logger(__name__, config=config)
logger.info("this outputs ok")

from tools import extractor
```

I get:

```
python3 main.py
2016-02-24 23:59:18,350 __main__     INFO     this outputs ok
2016-02-24 23:59:18,350 tools.extractor INFO     this doesn't appear in the log
```

Comment: I call extractor from within main.py. That's when it fails. Sorry about the ambiguity.

Comment: Okay, I edited the answer. Now extractor is imported from main.py. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: It wasn't quite right, but you made me realize what the actual problem was. It had to do with the `extractor.logger` was initialized before I had provided the configuration. See my answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem was. Since `import tools.extractor` is called *before* `get_logger(__name__, config=config)`, the logger in `extractor.py` is disabled. This is mentioned under the description for the `disable_existing_loggers` argument for [`dictConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig), which is set to `True` by default. Setting it to `False` solves the problem.